# flutter web safari ios no sound until user interaction detected

Tags: ios, flutter, google-chrome, safari

I am using [livekit](https://pub.dev/packages/livekit_client) to implement audio/video in a flutter app, but on ios on safari and chrome there is no sound until a user interaction(with the DOM) is detected like granting microphone permission. Does someone know a way to detect user interaction without asking for permission or using the dart:html package?

Comment: Unfortunately, especially in Webkit, given its very restrictive policies, audio playback is only allowed through a direct user action with the DOM. There are super ugly patches, such as playing a fake audio without sound immediately the user interacts, in order to "unlock" the browser session and be able to play, but it is not a very solid solution.

Comment: Please let me know if you find a solution for this.

Comment: actually, there is a solution, the livekit team added new functionality after i opened an issue, i will post an answer with the code

Comment: That is a fix from the LiveKit Plugin, not from Flutter Web or actually Webkit, not sure what LiveKit is using under the hood, they could be using something as I put it there, o some other workaround.

Comment: By just looking at the PR of LiveKit they are asking for a manual User trigger action: https://github.com/livekit/client-sdk-flutter/pull/285/files same as we already explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The livekit team added new functionality after i opened an [issue](https://github.com/livekit/client-sdk-flutter/issues/282)

the workaround is this:

```
EventsListener<RoomEvent> _listener
Room room
...

Future<bool?> showConfirmDialog() async{
  //here we show an alert dialog requesting permission
}

void _setUpListeners() => _listener
   
    ..on<AudioPlaybackStatusChanged>((event) async {
      if (!room.canPlaybackAudio) {
        print('Audio playback failed ..........');
        bool? yesno = await showConfirmDialog();
        if (yesno == true) {
          await room.startAudio();
        }
      }
    });
```